# asp.net core 2.1 Razor Page Redirection based on Roles during loigin

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, user-roles

IsInRole returns false after successful login. The same is working in other actions and controllers once successfully completely authenticated and loaded.

IsInRole is working in Other places, Is there any other method to achieve this.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, 
            ///set lockoutOnFailure: true
       var result = await 
            _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, 
            Input.Password, 
            Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");


                if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    return LocalRedirect("~/KeyRequests/AdminIndex");
                }
                else
                {
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");

               return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
       .....
       ....
      }
}
```

Comment: User is not populated in the same request as the sign in. Your best bet is to redirect to another page that then performs the redirect for you.  Remember to include the return url in your redirect

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some code snippets

Comment: @BobVale, Thanks got it. Just created a new razor page and Applied redirection login inside code behind

Comment: Glad to be of help